# PyQGIS crashes when using QgsRasterCalculator with multiple layers

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I am trying to do a calculation with multiple layers. Everything works exactly as it should when only calculating with one layer (e.g. `raster1@1 * 2`), but when I want to add two layers up, qgis crashes with the error: `windows fatal exception: access violation`. Here is my code:

```
list_shaduwen = ['path/to/raster1.tif','path/to/raster2.tif']
for layer in list_schaduwen:        
    lyr = QgsRasterLayer(layer)
    ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    ras.ref = layer.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]+'@1'
    refs.append(ras.ref)
    ras.raster = lyr
    ras.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append(ras)
                
output = 'path/to/output.tif'
exp = "%s+%s" % (refs[0],refs[1])
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(exp, output, 'GTiff', lyr.extent(), lyr.width(), lyr.height(), entries)                    
calc.processCalculation()
```

When I add a `break` before appending `ras.ref` to `entries`, and just do a calculation with a single raster and a single entry, it works as it should. However, when I fill the `ras.ref` list, the crash occurs, even when only doing calculations on one of the rasters.

Things I've already tried:

- changing the qgis temp folder
- using a different computer
- changing qgis user profiles
- restarting computer
- using different string formatting in `exp`
- setting `lyr` and `ras` to `None` after each iteration

Comment: Guys from [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47888) suggested *to try with a new profile (no plugins installed)*

Comment: Thanks, I've tried doing so but it still crashes, unfortunately.

Comment: I've got it to work now by hard coding ras.ref to a number of strings, and hard coding those strings in the exp formula. It works now, so I guess the problem is in formatting a list into the exp formula. 

Answers to the original question are still welcome though, as the method outlined in my question is still better for calculations with a large number of rasters, as it takes less lines of code. So it would still be useful to get that method to work.